# how to make regex go line by line to match two strings at the same time?

Tags: python, regex

The question is worded a bit weird, but I didn't know how else to ask it.

I am using wordnet to pull some definitions and I need to have regex both pull the part of speech and the definition from the output which goes like this... if I looked up the word study

```
Overview of verb study

1. reading, blah, blah (to read a book with the intent of learning)
2. blah blah blah (second definition of study)

Overview of noun study

1. blah blah blah (the object of ones study)
2. yadda yadda yadda (second definition of study)
```

I want to get this returned...

```
[('verb', 'to read a book with the intent of learning'), ('verb', 'second definition of study'), ('noun', 'the object of ones studying'), ('noun','second definition of study')]
```

I have the two regex expressions that match what I want, but I can't figure out how to go through the data in order to get the data structure I want in the end. Any ideas?

EDIT:

adding regex patterns

```
stripped_defs = re.findall('^\s*\d+\..*\(([^)"]+)', definitions, re.M)
pos = re.findall('Overview of (\w+)', definitions)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed the regex pattern that you are using to find the matches.

Comment: added to the main post

Comment: Ok, I see.  I thought maybe you already had found some way to get all the matches including both the part of speech and the definition in each match.  It would possible to do that in other languages, where variable-length lookbehinds are supported, but since python doesn't support that, I couldn't think of a way to do it.  So, I was curious how you had done it.  Apparently you ran into the same issue I did :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with python.  Perhaps someone else knows, if there another library for regex which adds support for a regex engine that does support variable-length lookbehinds.  Or, perhaps someone more clever than me will be able to come up with a way to do it with out the support for that feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My way is (`text` is the text):

1. split them by the `Overview of...`:

   ```
   >>> re.split('Overview of (\w+) study', text)[1:]
   ['verb', 
   '\n\n1. reading, blah, blah (to read a book with the intent of learning)\n2. blah blah blah (second definition of study)\n\n',
   'noun',
   '\n\n1. blah blah blah (the object of ones study)\n2. yadda yadda yadda (second definition of study)']

   >>> l = re.split('Overview of (\w+) study', text)[1:]
   ```
2. split that list like this:

   ```
   >>> [l[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(l), 2)]
   [['verb', 
     '\n\n1. reading, blah, blah (to read a book with the intent of learning)\n2. blah blah blah (second definition of study)\n\n'], 
    ['noun', 
     '\n\n1. blah blah blah (the object of ones study)\n2. yadda yadda yadda (second definition of study)']]

   >>> l = [l[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(l), 2)]
   ```

Then we can simply do:

```
>>> [[(i, k) for k in re.findall('\((.+?)\)', j)] for i, j in l]
[[('verb', 'to read a book with the intent of learning'),
  ('verb', 'second definition of study')],

 [('noun', 'the object of ones study'),
  ('noun', 'second definition of study')]]
```

To get your expect output:

```
final_list = []
for i in [[(i, k) for k in re.findall('\(.+?\)', j)] for i, j in l]:
    final_list.extend(i)

print(final_list)
```

Which gives:

```
[('verb', 'to read a book with the intent of learning'),
 ('verb', 'second definition of study'),

 ('noun', 'the object of ones study'),
 ('noun', 'second definition of study')]
```

---

Code:

```
l = re.split('Overview of (\w+) study', text)[1:]
l = [l[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(l), 2)]

# or just `final_list = l` if it doesn't matter
final_list = []

for i in [[(i, k) for k in re.findall('\(.+?\)', j)] for i, j in l]:
    final_list.extend(i)
```